# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

When I try to archive iOS Build, getting below error at the end of the process.

`Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)     at stableHash (node_modules/metro-cache/src/stableHash.js:19:8)     at Object.getCacheKey (/node_modules/metro-config/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:647:7)     at getTransformCacheKey (node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/getTransformCacheKey.js:32:19)     at new Transformer (node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:180:28)     at node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:58:29     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],   library: 'digital envelope routines',   reason: 'unsupported',   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED' } error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile'). TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')     at node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:95:34     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)     at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:14:24)     at _next (node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:36:9)     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.`

trying to archive React Native iOS Build

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you been able to find a fix?

Comment: No, Still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade node version, that solved the problem for me. v16 did the job.